# No events from notify icon

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, events, message

my application is running in Background completely but shows it's activity via a notification icon in system tray. Now I wanted to add a popup-menu to that notification icon. Unfortunately I do not receive any events from it. That's what I'm doing currently to create the icon and its event handler:

First create an invisible window to use it's event handler

```
ZeroMemory(&wc,sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
wc.cbSize=sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.lpfnWndProc=WndProc;
wc.hInstance=hInstance;
wc.lpszClassName=L"myCL";
RegisterClassEx(&wc);

hWnd=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,L"myCL",L"myWN",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,CW_USEDEFAULT,
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,1,1,NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);
```

Next create and show the icon itself:

```
ZeroMemory(&niData,sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA));
niData.cbSize=sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
niData.uID=IDI_AAAA; // the icon's identifier
niData.uFlags=NIF_ICON|NIF_MESSAGE|NIF_TIP;
niData.hIcon=(HICON)LoadImage(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_AAAA),IMAGE_ICON,
                              GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON),GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON),
                              LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
niData.hWnd=hWnd;
niData.uCallbackMessage=MY_TRAY_ICON_MESSAGE;
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD,&niData);
```

And the event handler that is assigned to the invisible window and where I would have assumed the events from the icon should arrive too:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
   switch(msg)
   {
      case WM_CLOSE:
         DestroyWindow(hwnd);
         break;
      case WM_DESTROY:
         PostQuitMessage(0);
         break;
      case MY_TRAY_ICON_MESSAGE: // this should be related to notification icon but is never called
         switch (lParam)
         {
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
            case WM_CONTEXTMENU:
               break;
         }
         break;
      default:
         return DefWindowProc(hwnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Anybody an idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a message loop?

Comment: David Heffernan: that's the reason - thanks!